# Can I ask a professor from another institution about getting involved in their research (undergrad CS)?

Tags: research-undergraduate, supervision, correspondence

I am going to be a senior next year and was hoping to get involved with research for my capstone. The professor I was planning on asking to advise me had been one of my favorite professors and seemed to have really interesting papers based on my readings of his work.

However, he will be moving schools this fall. He will be going to a school that I was hoping to apply to for grad school. We didn't build much of relationship from the class I had been in, would it be weird to reach out to him to see if I could possibly get involved in his work? Is it even really possibly to do work for a professor remotely like that at another school? I am not asking how I should correspond with the professor, I am more asking if that is an ok to get involved with research.

Comment: "Is it even really possibly to do work for a professor remotely like that at another school?", Yes, it is possible!

Comment: In my opinion it's okay to ask, but you should expect the answer might be no. You might have more luck if you find an official mentor at your own school; possibly, this professor might be reluctant to take on any formal responsibilities at your school but happy to talk science. Good luck.

Comment: Whether you can do research with a professor at another school depends on (among other things) your field. In mathematics, it's entirely possible; I've supervised research projects of students at other schools (or at my school while I was away). In a lab science, it seems impossible.